# Entity Framework setting Foreign Key reference to aspnet_users table w/o an entity class

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I'm trying to add a foreign key reference to the aspnet_users table to my Users table, to simply extend the aspnet_users.  I'm using EF and I don't want to create an aspnet_users entity class.  Is there a way to use the fluent API to create a foreign key reference to a table the EF isn't currently tracking?

I know it's not fluent API, but I tried the following w/ obvious fail:

```
[ForeignKey("aspnet_users.UserId")]
```

Thanks.

Comment: There are [plenty questions on this subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514733/entity-framework-code-first-aspnet-users-mapping-joins) and they all say: [don't map to aspnet_users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514733/entity-framework-code-first-aspnet-users-mapping-joins).

Comment: For clarity, you mean don't set a foreign key reference to it?

Comment: Well, rather: [don't map.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6521227/861716)

Comment: Yea, that's the crux of the issue.  Was avoiding mapping the table, but still wanted to set an FK reference to it.

Comment: @GertArnold uh, maybe I'm misunderstanding, but I cannot THINK of an application where "user" isn't a part of the domain. Whether it's Customer or SalesPerson, you're almost ALWAYS going to have a type in your domain that maps to the current user.
So, how do I get domain-specific information about the currently logged-in user without a mapping from the domain type to the User type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with fluent API either. You will have to execute the SQL manually to create the FK. If you are using database initializer then you can try something like this.

```
public class MyInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyDbContext context)
    {
        //your logic here
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("alter table MyTable
add constraint MyTable_MyColumn_FK FOREIGN KEY ( MyColumn ) references aspnet_users(UserId)");    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, assumed that this would be the case.