# Entity and ASP.NET Membership - how do I retrieve users?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have an entity query that is storing information with the aspnet_Users's UserID along with a form submission.  How can I access the the aspnet_users table in entity?  Do I have to create a new data model in order to access the built-in table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Entity Framework code first aspnet_Users mapping / joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514733/entity-framework-code-first-aspnet-users-mapping-joins), creating EF model for aspnet_* tables is not recommended. Rather, you should use ASPNET APIs for role/membership provider. In case of data sharing with other tables, create views and do not update aspnet_* tables.

Answer (score 0):

The Asp Net SQL Membership provider 'out of the box' provides its own functionality via a SQL Client connection, so you will need another connection string as well for Entity Framework.

As @rt2800 states, don't update the membership tables directly - use the Membership API.

But for read only query purposes, I would recommend that could create a SQL view on `aspnet_users / aspnet_membership` (join on UserId) and include this in your EF model. Something similar to `dbo.vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers`.